# Why in master asp the places of the content change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

Master page:

```
<div class="container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

<footer>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="col-xs-12 expo">
           <a href="" target="_blank">some site</a></div>
       </div>
</footer>
```

Why the page show first foter and then contentplaceholder?

Comment: note: The FOOTER is displayed in the middle. half of the ContentPlaceHolder is displayed, in the middle of the FOOTER, and only at the end of the other half of the ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: Sounds like your CSS is not correct. To debug this we need to see an example which displays the problem. Note that we need the CSS and HTML output, not the master page code.

Comment: What to show? There is no display of any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I used the table I had to add

```
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```